# Replace iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Apologies if I have created new thread for this, but I didn't get a solution elsewhere. 
I am newbie to web designing and I was playing around with the `<iframe>` tag.

I used javascript to display a graphical chart from `Google Sheets`. Every time I click on the link which opens the chart (connected by `iframe`), the chart gets displayed once again below the previous chart and my `HTML` page gets elongated. I don't want that to happen. Instead, I would like to replace the old chart with the new chart in the same margins of previous generated charts.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    x.setAttribute("src", "#Link_to_Google_sheet_chart");
    x.height = "400";
    x.width = "545";
    x.style.margin = "100px 20px 200px 450px";
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not supposed to have a link prefixed with `#`. Use `https://link.com`

Have you tried this?

```
x.src = "https://link.com";
```

If that doesn't work, maybe try this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    x.setAttribute("src", "https://link.com");
    x.height = "400";
    x.width = "545";
    x.style.margin = "100px 20px 200px 450px";
    x.id = "iframe-0";
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
function switch() {
    document.getElementById('iframe-0').style.display = "none";
    // create new iframe here, then append it
    var y = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    y.setAttribute("src", "https://link.com");
    y.height = "400";
    y.width = "545";
    y.style.margin = "100px 20px 200px 450px";
    y.id = "iframe-1";
    document.body.appendChild(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a id to the iframe and replace it next time as below

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('unique-id');
    if(typeof(x) !== 'undefined'){ //if iframe is appended only change src
      return x.setAttribute("src", "#Link_to_Google_sheet_chart");
    }
    x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    x.id = 'unique-id';
    x.setAttribute("src", "#Link_to_Google_sheet_chart");
    x.height = "400";
    x.width = "545";
    x.style.margin = "100px 20px 200px 450px"; 
    return document.body.appendChild(x);

}
```